# Problem with testing suffix of \jobname, \c_sys_jobname_str

Tags: conditionals, strings, xstring, jobname

I have latex files with file names `T-BA-DEC-de-0001_Title1.tex` and `T-BA-DEC-de-0002_Text2.tex`. I would like to switch code depending on these file names. Up to now I tried to solve the problem using `\ifthenelse`and with the xstring package:

```
\usepackage{xstring}

\IfBeginWith{\detokenize\expandafter{\c_sys_jobname_str}}{\detokenize{T-BA-DEC-de-0001}}{TRUE}{FALSE}
\IfBeginWith{\detokenize\expandafter{\c_sys_jobname_str}}{\detokenize{T-BA-DEC-de-0002}}{TRUE}{FALSE}
```

Whatever I tried, the `\IfBeginWith` always runs into the FALSE condition or creates runtime errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to be mixing `expl3` and `xstring`, which seems a bit odd (though `\jobname` is a bit strange, admittedly). Could you show us a complete example: with `\ExplSyntaxOn` added the above does work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `expl3` for `\c_sys_jobname_str`, I'd be minded to go the whole way and simply code up a quick 'starts with' test myself. Something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \WolfiG_test:nnTF #1#2
  { \exp_args:Ne \__WolfiG_test:nn { \tl_to_str:n {#1} } {#2} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \WolfiG_test:nnTF { nV }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__WolfiG_test:nn #1#2
  {
    \cs_set:Npn \__WolfiG_test:w ##1 #1 ##2 \q_stop
      { \tl_if_blank:nTF {##1} }
    \__WolfiG_test:w #2 #1 \q_stop
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__WolfiG_test:w { }
\WolfiG_test:nVTF { T-BA-DEC-de-0001 } \c_sys_jobname_str \T \F
\WolfiG_test:nVTF { T-BA-DEC-de-0002 } \c_sys_jobname_str \T \F
```

Or if you want to use 'generic string' functions

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \WolfiG_test:nnTF #1#2
  {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF {#1} { \str_range:nnn {#2} { 1 } { \str_count:n {#1} } }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \WolfiG_test:nnTF { nV }
\WolfiG_test:nVTF { T-BA-DEC-de-0001 } \c_sys_jobname_str \T \F
\WolfiG_test:nVTF { T-BA-DEC-de-0002 } \c_sys_jobname_str \T \F
```

where I've used `\str_range:nnn` to extract a substring from `#2` (the job name) that is the same length as `#1` (the test string), then compared the two.